# Jetpack compose TextField RTL support

Tags: textfield, android-jetpack-compose

XML `TextField`, automatically response to RTL text and align it to right.

```xml
    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/textview_first"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="سلااااااممممممم"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/button_first"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

[image: 1]     *   [image: 2]

But, In Compose `TextField`, it's stick to left.
Is there any way to have `TextField` to align RTL text to right and LTR text to left?

Comment: Please post a sample code showing your RTL.

Comment: @Johann I added xml code to my question.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Based on @Poran answer, you must add `textStyle` to `TextField` :

```kotlin
TextField(
   value = name,
   ...
   textStyle = TextStyle(color = Color.Black, textDirection = TextDirection.Content)
)
```

Answer (score 4):

**This is working for text view and text field->**

Text->

```
Text(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
        text = text,
        fontSize = 20.sp,
        fontFamily = FontFamily.SansSerif,
        style = TextStyle(textDirection = TextDirection.Rtl)
    )
```

TextField->

```
var value by remember {
            mutableStateOf("")
        }


TextField(value = value,
          onValueChange = { value = it },
          modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
          textStyle = TextStyle(textDirection = TextDirection.Rtl))
```

Comment: Very nice as this even places the cursor of TextField at the end of the text :)

Comment: nice but this solution will align the text to the right without considering the actual text direction. Setting textDirection to TextDirection.Content will set the alignment automatically

Answer (score 2):

You have to add `textDirection` on `textStyle` `textStyle = TextStyle(color = Color.Black, textDirection = TextDirection.ContentOrLtr)`

```
BasicTextField(
                value = text,
                onValueChange = {
                text = it
                onSearch(it)
            },
                maxLines = 1,
                singleLine = true,
                textStyle = TextStyle(color = Color.Black, textDirection = TextDirection.ContentOrLtr),
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .shadow(5.dp, CircleShape)
                    .background(Color.White, CircleShape)
                    .padding(horizontal = 20.dp, vertical = 12.dp)
                    .onFocusChanged {
                        isDisableHint = it.isFocused && text.isEmpty()
                    }
            )
```

Updated my answer:  I think it will solve your problem

```
textStyle = TextStyle(color = Color.Black, textDirection = TextDirection.ContentOrLtr)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, `textDirection` have negative impact on LTR text and align it to right of `TextField`

Comment: I don't understand what do you meant?

Comment: @Paran I mean, if you set `textDirection = TextDirection.Rtl` and type English text into `TextField` , text stick at right of `TextField`. I want a `TextField` that if you type english text, behave ltr support and if you type arabic, behave rtl support like XML material `TextField`.

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: I think, should accept this as an answer.